# What does a "Nonetype" object error on the public VQGA code mean?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am using the code from [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1go6YwMFe5MX6XM9tv-cnQiSTU50N9EeT#scrollTo=ZdlpRFL8UAlW), which is publicly available code for generating AI images. It has been working perfectly until recently, when it's suddenly started giving me this error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-854eb7d4187d> in <module>()
     24 if imagen_inicial == "None":
     25     imagen_inicial = None
---> 26 elif imagen_inicial.startswith("http"):
     27     imagen_inicial = download_img(imagen_inicial)
     28 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Does anyone have an idea what's going wrong?

Comment: That is an *attribute error*, not a "nontype error". It is telling you that `None` doesn't have a `.startswith` attribute, so presumably, `imagen_inicial == None`.

Comment: That line would  be ok if `imagen_inicial` was a string, which has the `startswith` method.  But for some reason it is `None` (not the string "None").

Answer (score 1):

It's because in that input `imagen_inicial` is `None`.

To fix it you should add another `elif`:

```
if imagen_inicial == "None":
    imagen_inicial = None
elif imagen_inicial = None:
    pass
elif imagen_inicial.startswith("http"):
    imagen_inicial = download_img(imagen_inicial)
```